# Define Type of Immutable Map With Builder

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am trying to make a `Map<BooleanSupplier, List<String>>` as part of my flow I make the suppliers and then try to use an immutable map builder.

Something like:

```
 //Build up BooleanSuppliers
 Map<BooleanSupplier, List<String>> bsList = ImmutableMap.builder()
 .put(bs1, Collections.singletonList("bs1string"))
 .put(bs2, Arrays.asList("bs4","bs6"))
 ....
 .build();
```

The problem is that intellij says that the types are not convertible even when I do an explicit cast because the ImmutableMap is of type `<Object, Object>`. Is there a way to explicitly cast or initialize the immutable map builder to be of type `ImmutableMap<BooleanSupplier, List<String>>`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Specify the generic type explicitely when calling `builder()`:

```
Map<BooleanSupplier, List<String>> bsList = 
    ImmutableMap.<BooleanSupplier, List<String>>builder()
        .put(...)
        .build();
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this might be better expressed as an `ImmutableListMultimap`.